# Angular ui-switch is calling function after loading on HTML

Tags: angular, angular15

I am working on Angular-15

here is my HTML code

```
<table *ngIf="child.submenu">
                    <tr *ngFor="let subchild of child.submenu.items" class="isShown" [ngClass]="{'has-sub':(subchild.submenu),'active': subchild.isSelected && !subchild.submenu, 'open': subchild.isOpen && subchild.submenu}">
                      <td>
                        <a class="menu-item">{{subchild.title}}</a>
                        <table *ngIf="subchild.submenu && !subchild.excludeInVertical" class="menu-content">
                          <tr *ngFor="let subchild of subchild.submenu.items" [ngClass]="{'active': subchild.isSelected && !subchild.submenu}">
                            <td>
                              <a class="menu-item" *ngIf="!subchild.event" routerLink="{{subchild.page}}" (click)="toggleMenu($event, subchild, true)">{{subchild.id}} &nbsp; {{subchild.title}}</a>
                              <a class="menu-item" *ngIf="subchild.event" (click)="callFunction(subchild.event, subchild)">{{subchild.title}}</a>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                      <td><ui-switch class="switchery" switchColor="white" color="rgb(55, 188, 155)" name="{{'item-' + subchild.id + '-name'}}" [(ngModel)]="subchild.isChecked" (ngModelChange)="enableDisableMenuOption($event, subchild)"></ui-switch></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
```

Here is my component file

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, ChangeDetectorRef, AfterViewInit  } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuConfigurationService } from "./menu-configuration.service"
import { ViewChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu-configuration',
  templateUrl: './menu-configuration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu-configuration.component.css']
})
export class MenuConfigurationComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  child: any;
  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document,
    private menuConfigService: MenuConfigurationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchAllMenuRoleWise();
  }

  saveMenuConfiguration(roleId: number, menu: any): void {
    this.menuConfigService.saveRoleConfiguration(roleId, menu)
      .subscribe({
        next: (data) => {
          this._menuSettingsConfig.vertical_menu = data;
          console.log(data);
        },
        error: (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      });
  }
}
```

`ui-switch` is from `import { UiSwitchModule } from 'ngx-ui-switch';` of version `"ngx-ui-switch": "^14.0.3"`

Problem is when UI load or DOM is ready, `ui-switch` triggers my function which I dont wanted to do so.

Here are few screen shots

I tried using with `AfterViewInit` set boolean flags, but It is creating too much complicated lines of code since I am not much expertise in Angular :)
[image]

Comment: ngModelChange will be triggered before ngModel value changes, that's how it works.

Comment: Ohh, I see. then to avoid on load calls, I have to elliminate ngModel ? but then I am loosing the bindings, what could be the appropriate way in this case ?

Comment: I never used that package, but on the npmjs I see it doesn't use ngModelChange in any example. There are other methods mentioned though. Also it seems that ngModel is enough?